# Filter and Count JSON object of objects by object parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a question relating to `filter` and `count` of `JSON object` data.

How can I `filter` and `count` the `objects` where **SIT** = `false`? In the example data this would be 3.

And the count if the total number of SIT? In the example data this would be 4.

I would want to do the same for PROD.

I have tried the following:

```
var SIT = response.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.environment === "SIT";
});
```

and

```
var SIT = [];
SIT = response.data.cis.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.environment === "SIT";
});
```

**Here is my data:**

```
{
  "cis": {
    "dsbgchop193": {
      "environment": "SIT", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "dsbgchop194": {
      "environment": "SIT", 
      "is_compliant": true
    }, 
    "dsbgchop195": {
      "environment": "SIT", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "dsbgchop196": {
      "environment": "SIT", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "id": "2017.10.17", 
    "psbgwais1v": {
      "environment": "PROD", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "psbgwais2v": {
      "environment": "PROD", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "rsbgwais1v": {
      "environment": "PROD", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "rsbgwais2v": {
      "environment": "PROD", 
      "is_compliant": true
    }
  }, 
  "rating": "", 
  "ssl": {}
}
```

Comment: filter works on array

Comment: object does not have filter function. Use for.. in or for .. of

Comment: @Sajeetharan thank you. My bad. Any suggestions perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "cis": {
    "dsbgchop193": {
      "environment": "SIT", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "dsbgchop194": {
      "environment": "SIT", 
      "is_compliant": true
    }, 
    "dsbgchop195": {
      "environment": "SIT", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "dsbgchop196": {
      "environment": "SIT", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "id": "2017.10.17", 
    "psbgwais1v": {
      "environment": "PROD", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "psbgwais2v": {
      "environment": "PROD", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "rsbgwais1v": {
      "environment": "PROD", 
      "is_compliant": false
    }, 
    "rsbgwais2v": {
      "environment": "PROD", 
      "is_compliant": true
    }
  }, 
  "rating": "", 
  "ssl": {}
}

var statistics = Object.keys(data.cis).reduce(function (stats, key) {
  var item = data.cis[key];
  if (item.environment === 'SIT') {
    stats.totalCount += 1;

    if (item.is_compliant) {
      stats.compliantCount += 1;
    }
  }
  return stats;
}, { totalCount: 0, compliantCount: 0 });

console.log('statistics : ', statistics);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! Like your method. Especially using ES5. I am still learning ES6.

Answer (score 1):

You could count it with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check the condition while using the keys of the object.

```js
var data = { cis: { dsbgchop193: { environment: "SIT", is_compliant: false }, dsbgchop194: { environment: "SIT", is_compliant: true }, dsbgchop195: { environment: "SIT", is_compliant: false }, dsbgchop196: { environment: "SIT", is_compliant: false }, id: "2017.10.17", psbgwais1v: { environment: "PROD", is_compliant: false }, psbgwais2v: { environment: "PROD", is_compliant: false }, rsbgwais1v: { environment: "PROD", is_compliant: false }, rsbgwais2v: { environment: "PROD", is_compliant: true } }, rating: "", ssl: {} },
    count = Object.keys(data.cis).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r + !!(data.cis[k].environment === 'SIT' && !data.cis[k].is_compliant);
    }, 0);

console.log(count);
```

For a count of all, you could group by `environment` and `is_compliant` properties.

```js
function inc(object, path) {
    var last = path.pop(),
        level = path.reduce(function (r, k) { return r[k] = r[k] || {}; }, object);

    level[last] = (level[last] || 0) + 1;
}

var data = { cis: { dsbgchop193: { environment: "SIT", is_compliant: false }, dsbgchop194: { environment: "SIT", is_compliant: true }, dsbgchop195: { environment: "SIT", is_compliant: false }, dsbgchop196: { environment: "SIT", is_compliant: false }, id: "2017.10.17", psbgwais1v: { environment: "PROD", is_compliant: false }, psbgwais2v: { environment: "PROD", is_compliant: false }, rsbgwais1v: { environment: "PROD", is_compliant: false }, rsbgwais2v: { environment: "PROD", is_compliant: true } }, rating: "", ssl: {} },
    count = {};

Object.keys(data.cis).forEach(function (k) {
    if (typeof data.cis[k] === 'object') {
        inc(count, [data.cis[k].environment, data.cis[k].is_compliant]);
    }
});

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`filter` is a function on arrays, not on objects, that's why it doesn't work.

You can use `Object.keys` to get the keys,
and map them to the objects in `response.cis` to get an array so that you can filter:

```
var items = Object.keys(response.cis).map(k => response.cis[k]);

items.filter(o => o.environment === "SIT" && !o.is_compliant);
// prints 3

items.filter(o => o.environment === "SIT");
// prints 4
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Or with a dedicated class:

```js
let data =  {
  "cis": {
      "dsbgchop193": {"environment": "SIT", "is_compliant": false}
    , "dsbgchop194": {"environment": "SIT", "is_compliant": true}
    , "dsbgchop195": {"environment": "SIT", "is_compliant": false} 
    , "dsbgchop196": {"environment": "SIT", "is_compliant": false} 
    , "id": "2017.10.17"
    , "psbgwais1v": {"environment": "PROD", "is_compliant": false} 
    , "psbgwais2v": {"environment": "PROD", "is_compliant": false} 
    , "rsbgwais1v": {"environment": "PROD", "is_compliant": false}
    , "rsbgwais2v": {"environment": "PROD", "is_compliant": true}}, "rating": "", "ssl": {}
}
  
class FiltrableObject {
  constructor (h) {
    this.h = h;
  }
  filter (params) {
    return this.values.filter(params)
  }
  get values () {
    if (undefined===this._values){this._values = Object.values(this.h)}
    return this._values;
  }
}

function operate() {
  let filtrable = new FiltrableObject(data.cis);
  
  let notCompliantSIT = filtrable.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.environment === "SIT" && !obj.is_compliant;
  })

  let allSIT = filtrable.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.environment === "SIT";
  })

  console.log('notCompliantSITs count:',notCompliantSIT.length)
  console.log('allSITs count:', allSIT.length)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0;}
```

```html
<button onclick="operate()">OPERATE!</button>
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer! Great +1